# playwright element in dom but not in locator, runs fine in debug mode by putting a debug point on top of it

Tags: javascript, d3.js, automated-tests, playwright

```
locator.click: Target closed
=========================== logs ===========================
  waiting for frame "#sandbox-test-db-container"
  selector resolved to visible <iframe lang="en" scrolling="yes" title="Content body" i…></iframe>
waiting for selector "#sandbox-test-db-container >> control=enter-frame >> g:nth-child(273) > circle"
  selector resolved to visible <circle r="7" cx="209.86857670732482" cy="106.8619269650…></circle>
attempting click action
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and stable
    element is not stable - waiting...
element was detached from the DOM, retrying
  waiting for frame "#sandbox-test-db-container"
  selector resolved to visible <iframe lang="en" scrolling="yes" title="Content body" i…></iframe>
waiting for selector "#sandbox-test-db-container >> control=enter-frame >> g:nth-child(273) > circle"
============================================================
```

if i run in debug mode by putting a debug point on top of it. it runs successfully.
I am trying to click a slider(switch) to render d3 map and then click on a circle in d3 map.
Test snippet

```
      this.page.frameLocator('#sandbox-test-db-container').locator('.oui-react-slider').click(),
      this.page.frameLocator('#sandbox-test-db-container').locator('g:nth-child(273) > circle').click(),
      this.page.frameLocator('#sandbox-test-db-container').locator('[aria-label="Select all"]').click()
```